# vscode intellisense - cannot find module ts(2307) in excluded directory

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

In my tsconfig.json I excluded folder

```
"src/__test__"
```

from compilation. The problem is now VS Code cannot find module. I run tests with Jest without problem, the modules are resolved but this message is annoying. I also cannot use autocomplete.
Is there a way to create seperate typescript config files for tests and source code? So far I created tsconfig.test.json file with "extend": "../../tsconfig.json" but it doesn't work as I expected. Compiler read only base tsconfig.json.

> Cannot find module <..> or its corresponding type
> declarations.ts(2307)

> `tsconfig.json`

```
{
      "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
        "sourceMap": false,
        "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "rootDir": "",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "paths": {
          "components/*": ["src/components/*"],
          "utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
          "api/*": ["src/api/*"],
          "src/*": ["src/*"]
        }
      },
      "exclude": ["src/__tests__"]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround solution.

By adding these line of code in jest config, you'll prevent jest from running *test.js files in dist folder:

```js
{
    ...,
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
      "<rootDir>/dist/"
    ]
}
```

And then you can comment the exclude line in tsconfig so that the error would go away.